# Cakephp save associated on a model that is in a belongs_to AND a has_many relationship

Tags: cakephp

Using cakephp, I have the models Institution, Address and User. The relationships are:

```
An Institution has_many Addresses, Users.
An User belongs_to Address, Institution.
An Address belongs_to an Institution and has_many Users;
```

When A Institution is created the Address and a User should also be saved.
So in the Institution controller's add method I tried the following:

```
if ($this->Institution->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {
            // set Users default address to institutions initial address
            $this->User->set(array(
                'address_id' => $this->Address->id
            ));
            $this->User->save();
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The institution has been saved.'));
            return; //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

This however gives me `Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'address_id' doesn't have a default value` because `address_id` must not be `NULL`. It works on some systems, on some it does not.

The request data looks like this

```
array(
'Institution' => array(
    'name' => 'name1',
    'country_id' => '83',
    'sigil' => 'sig1',
    'count_media_down' => '0'
),
'Address' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'street' => 'street1',
        'zipcode' => '12345',
        'city' => 'city1',
        'is_default' => true,
        'country_id' => '83'
    )
),
'User' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'username' => 'user1',
        'email' => 'email@email.com',
        'first_name' => 'first1',
        'last_name' => 'last1',
        'department' => 'dep1',
        'language' => 'de',
        'role' => 'exchanger'
    )
)
)
```

I suspect it is a problem with the conflict of has_many and belongs_to user.
What would be the correct way to solve this?

Comment: why did you set that address_id could not be NULL? I understand that as a general rule you don't want a user who has not an address. But an user can be temporarily without an address for technical reason (i.e. when creating a user just before assigning an address to him). I would remove that constrain

Comment: If there is no other solution I will remove it, yes. I thought cakephp maybe could handle such cases and do the right thing, like sorting out the id before creating the record or something similar. It also bugs me, that it works on some systems (MAMP on OSX, Linux Mint 16) and does not on another one (OpenSUSE 13.1) so I thought it might be related to MariaDB vs. MySQL or something like that..